# Перепрошивка андроида на Windows

Tags: windows, android

А на `NetTAB THOR` можно перепрошить?

Comment: на MacOS сразу перешивай, чего мелочиться :)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос не имеет отношения к программированию.

Answer (score 1):

нет смысла. Андроид просто лучше:)

Но если честно,  то нужно понимать, что внутри у планшета arm процессор. Поэтому обычна винда там не будет работать (она умеет только на x86 и alpha, которых пол хэшкода в глаза не видели). Новая, 8 винда работает на arm процессорах, но для них нужно свои, специальные программы (процессор то совсем другой). А портировать программы - это ещё то занятие. Программы, написанные под .NET может быть запустятся, но опять же, не факт.

Но есть оригинальный выход. Если нужно просто показать, что на планшете запущена виндовс, то можно поставить [эмулятор-виртуальную машину](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.motioncoding.emulator) и на нем установить уже винду.

Comment: китайский планшет, андроид глюканый, мне хотя бы сеть нормально настроить, в настройках APN никак не хочет сохранять новую запись...

Comment: читайте профильные сайты типа 4pda.ru и china-iphone.ru  
почитайте какое у вас там железо стоит, многие прошивки идут уже с поддержкой стандартного железа, я так свой китайский планшет шил,  при прошивке оно справивало какой проц стоит и шила уже рабочую прошивку, выбор там был чтото 60+ наборов....

Comment: может быть андроид с C# подойдет? вот статья http://habrahabr.ru/post/170629/

Comment: всем спасибо, все расходимся